# Android ListView with “tabs”

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, tabs, tabbed

picture from a reddit news feed

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YXMK.jpg)

I am creating an app with a list view that is populated from a sqlite database.  Each of the data base items can have a status of either “resolved” or “unresolved”.

I want the listview to have 3 “tabs” with the labels “all items”, “resolved items”, and “unresolved items” with correspoding sqlite queries to populate each.

It should behave similarly to the one pictured.

I assumed this would be a tabbed listview and have been watching tutorials for a week based on those search words and it’s taking taking me down a dark rabbit hole of fragments and changing gradles and so on.  I’m not sure tabs are what i really want.

Could I do this with three buttons instead where each button would run a different query and populate my listviewcontainer?

Ideally, when the page is opened, the first “tab” would be highlighted and the listview populated with all records.  As the other tabs are pressed, they would highlight and a new query would run.

Would another approach work better?

I’m not asking for code, I just want some conceptual direction on where to focus my research.

Comment: What have you attempted already? Post your code.

Comment: You could use `TabLayout` with three `Fragment` elements that will contain different list with proper database query and it is not so hard, if you're ablt to use shared `ViewModel`.
In other way you are able to set 3 `Buttons` and one list view, and simply populate the list in button `onClick` with notifying that `notifyDataSetChanged()`. Or you can perform one query and then just filter items and set them as list content without disturbing the whole list. I could provide you code if you could give details about prefered way to solve problem.

Comment: @JakeB ... no code yet.  As I said, I’ve been reading up on tabbed views because that’s what I assumed I wanted, but the explanations I’m finding for tabbed listviews seem like a really complicated way to perform what should be a relatively simple/common task.

Comment: @Blind Kai ... thank you for your feedback.  I think buttons are going to be the more straight forward approach.  Still not sure how I will make the Activity default open with one of the buttons already pushed, but I’ll cross that bridge when I get to it.  Time to get back to work on this.

Comment: You're able to get the needed results using `RecyclerView` I'm testing provided code right know, wait for upd.

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right you need to filter your query results in different lists. Making a lot of queries into database is not the thing that is preferable specially if it's going to be a long process and doing it a lot of times is time and memory consuming.
So to make it work you could simple store your full query result in one variable and change the `RecyclerView` data using custom method `setList()` and later using `notifyDataSetChanged()` to apply the changes.

To make it work you need to get understanding of "how RecyclerView works" and then you will be fine.

So after providing the right logic you would be able to simple split your whole query result as it's needed (by element values for example) as it's showed above:

About the code below:

- `list` - is your query result
- `leftFilterList` or `rightFilterList` - are lists that contain sorted items
- `adapter.setList(rightFilterList)` - sets the `RecyclerView` data (filtered items in our case)
- `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` - is used to notify `RecyclerView` that list was changed, and he need to rebuild it.

So we have two `Button`s and logic that fillter items in differend ways.

```
public void left(View view) {
    ArrayList<ExampleItem> leftFilterList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (ExampleItem item : list) {
        if (item.getTitle().length() % 2 == 0) {
            leftFilterList.add(item);
        }
    }
    adapter.setList(leftFilterList);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void right(View view) {
    ArrayList<ExampleItem> rightFilterList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (ExampleItem item : list) {
        if (item.getTitle().length() % 2 == 1) {
            rightFilterList.add(item);
        }
    }
    adapter.setList(rightFilterList);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

And the result of filtering*:

[image]

- - sorry for wrong toast text. It shows the whole list size.

Comment: did you seriously just write all that in 94 seconds?!? I want to be you when I grow up.

Comment: @Matthew I'm currently working with `RecyclerView` and lists at all so I already got a project with setted `RecyclerView` so I just added two buttons and coded them as you could see above. It's not hard to set it, just take a look in Documentation and Videos.